# In Toki Tori, which levels contain sunbeams to get the new Get A Tan achievement?

Tags: toki-tori

Added for the Steam Summer Camp I guess, there's a new achievement on Toki Tori: Get a Tan. You need to stand in 10 sunbeams to get it.

I've heard indirectly from the developers that they are all in the forest levels. Does anyone have a list of which levels they are in? I have found 1-6 on Normal, but standing in it did nothing - can't tell if it was a wrong one, or just not working yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just finished the achievement. You stand in the sunbeams for just a second, and you'll see your sunbeam count go up, i.e. 1/10. You get the achievement for the last beam. If that's not working for you, make sure Toki Tori has been updated.

I also made a [video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfoXNiC1SIg) for this achievement:

Comment: I accepted this simply for that amazing video guide.

Answer (score 12):

The Sunbeams required for the achievement can be found in the following levels.

- 1-6 Normal
- 1-8 Normal
- 1-11 Normal
- 1-1 Hard
- 1-3 Hard
- 1-4 Hard
- 1-5 Hard
- 1-6 Hard
- 1-7 Hard
- Bonus Stage 3

Comment: This is great. Is there one exact square you must stand? Do you have to stand there for a long time? Or is the achievement just currently non-functional?

Comment: It marks them off 1/10, 2/10 as you get them, just need to step in them to activate.

Comment: @Dunhamzzzz I did, yet nothing happened. The achievement didn't show up in game either (as locked)

Comment: it appears in the sun beam for me as I get it

Answer (score 0):

They are the straight down sunbeamn, not the slanted background ones.

The icon will appear when you find the right one.

In world 1-6 Normal, it's in the top right